SpringBoot3 Migration using PathVariable is not showing it as a Parameter, when call is done throwing 500 Internal Server Error
We migrated our Spring Boot 2.7.15 Application to 3.2.1. We updated our pom.xml to reflect all 3.2.1 specific dependencies
After the Spring Boot 3.2.1 Migration, noticed that for any @GetMapping including @PathVariable
when request is made, we are getting 500 Internal Server Error.
Also Swagger shows:
GET  api/account/{fiscalYear}  but does not show Parameters. Try it out also doesn't show any parameters.
This was working fine with Spring Boot 2.7.15, having issue after Migration to Spring Boot 3.2.1
@RequestMapping("api/account")
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    AccountService accountService;


    @GetMapping(path = "/{fiscalYear}")
    public Response getAccountDetails(@PathVariable int fiscalYear) {
    ....
    }
}

Updated all pom entries to reflect Spring Boot 3.2.1

Please share the server log related to the error. 500 means that there was an exception thrown.

updating the method to following fixed the problem:
@GetMapping(path = "/{fiscalYear}")
public Response getAccountDetails(@PathVariable("fiscalYear") int fiscalYear) {
....
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
